# If a child class extend Base class Exception

Tags: java, oop, exception, inheritance

I had a doubt.
Imagine If we have a class A that implements the  method 
For example

```
 private void methodA(int index) throws Exception, Error {

 }
```

And if we have a Class B that extends the first class A.
My questions is, can class B implement

```
 private void methodA(int index) throws Exception, Error {
 }
```

And which method will be called under which circumstance!!

Thanks

Comment: You can't use `throws` without specifying a `Throwable`. That's a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

If your methods weren't declared "private", this would just be standard polymorphism.  Because they're private, the rules are a bit different.  The version in class A can only be called from code that's in class A.  The version in class B can only be called from code that's actually *written* in class B (as opposed to code that class B gets by extending class A).

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer, which I wrote before noticing that the methods were declared as private.  Apologies to the person who upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**,  you can **implement** the `methodA` method in class B, but, pay attention, you are not overriding it.

Your method is declared ad `private` so is not "visible" from extending classes.

If your intention is to make your method overridable, you need to declare it as `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try :)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base;
        base = new A();
        System.out.println(base.doSth());

        base = new B();
        System.out.println(base.doSth());
    }
}

abstract class Base {
    public abstract String doSth();
}

class A extends Base {
    @Override
    public String doSth() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String doSth() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you answered the question?  It looks to me like you just restated it, and changed "private" to "public".

Answer (score -1):

I think you wonna override the super-class method, and to do this, the method on sub-class must have the same signature of super-class method.

You can call these methods in following ways:

- Suppose `test1` is an instance of `classA`, `teste1.methodA(index)` will execute the implementation on super-class.
- Suppose `test2` is an instance of `classB`, `test2.methodA(index)` will execute the sub-class method.
- In `classB` you can invoque the super class method (if the method is not`private`), something like :

  ```
  public class ClassB extends ClassA
  {
      ...
      super.methodA(index);
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: The last part is incorrect. You can't invoke the superclass method, because it's private.

Comment: None of this is correct.  Private methods don't work this way.  As I said in my answer, what matters is which class the calling code is written in.  Not the class of the object that the method is called on.  There is no polymorphism here.